# Rewire edges in a graph while preserving degrees

Tags: r, vector, permutation, graph-theory

Suppose I have a graph with 5 nodes. Each node has a certain number of edges (no edges from a node to itself), those are called the degree of that node. I want to create a new set of edges so that each node has the same degree as before.

My first attempt is to create a vector in which each node v has degree(v) entries, sample that vector (to get a permutation of that vector), split that vector into two vectors of equal length and *check if the nth entry in the two vectors is different* (call this **condition 1**). If that is the case, the two vectors would form an edge list with no edges from a node to itself.

For 5 nodes this would work fine, but for 1000+ nodes and some nodes with degree (exceeding 100) it takes a lot of repeating until *condition 1* is satisfied.

My second attempt was to `sample()`, create the two vectors and sample again from those pairs of nodes which did not satisfy *condition 1*, then add split the result and add them to the remaining two vectors and repeat that a couple of times until either *condition 1* is satisfied or the set of nodes in violation of *condition 1* cannot be properly matched to form proper edges (i.e. those not in violation of *condition 1*).

Explicitly computing all possible vectors (of node labels), removing the invalid one and then randomly picking one is not a good idea for large graphs. It would take too much memory and just computing all of them probably takes a lot of time as well.

#### What I'm looking for

Given a vector of nodes (just integer labels, even length), return a randomly chosen (so it would need to use something like `sample()` or some other function based on pseudo random numbers) set of pairs of nodes (preferably as two vectors which form an edge list) so that each edge connects two different nodes and the degrees of the nodes remain the same.

#### Coding example

A small coding example using 5 nodes:
`E<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)`

A valid solution:

`V1<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,4)`
`V2<-c(2,3,4,5,3,4,5)`

Another valid solution (this has a repeat edge, which is allowed):

`V1<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3)`
`V2<-c(2,3,4,5,4,4,5)`

Not a valid solution (this has a self edge, which is not allowed):

`V1<-c(1,2,1,1,2,2,4)`
`V2<-c(1,3,4,5,3,4,5)`

Using (exotic) R libraries is good, they are especially welcomed if they manage to speed things up.

#### Additional information

Rather than just having a vector of the nodes (with repetitions as many times as they appear in edges), it may be assumed that the actual edges in the original graph are also provided.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem is called [*degree-preserving randomization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree-preserving_randomization#Example). It can be done by repeatedly rewiring, which works as follows:

Sample two edges, let's call them AB and CD. If A is different from C and D is different from b, the sampled edges would be removed and replaced by AC and BD. By repeating this sufficiently many times, the edges are randomised.

Of course, this could also be applied to vector example by making a list of edges and randomly sampling them.

Answer (score 1):

I think an alternative way to solve this problem is using a model of growth such as [Erdos-Renyi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) which is helpful to generate random graphs.

You said, "I want to create a new set of edges so that each node has the same degree as before." If I were you, I would modify the Erdos-Renyi model to generate the new graph.

First, you need a create a graph. The following code (precisely the function randomGraph) can do it for you.

```
#install.packages("network")
library(network)

increaseDegree <- function(key, degreeMap) {
  keyChar = as.character(key)
  if(is.null(degreeMap[[keyChar]])) {
    degreeMap[[keyChar]] = 0
  }
  degreeMap[[keyChar]] = degreeMap[[keyChar]]  + 1
  return(degreeMap)
}

getDegree <- function(key, degreeMap) {
  keyChar = as.character(key)
  if(is.null(degreeMap[[keyChar]])) {
    return (0)
  } else {
    return (degreeMap[[keyChar]])
  }
}

randomGraph <- function(numNodes) {
  degreeMap <- new.env(hash=T, parent=emptyenv())
  initialNumNodes = 2;
  g <- network.initialize(numNodes, directed = FALSE);
  add.edge(g,1,2);
  increaseDegree(1, degreeMap)
  increaseDegree(2, degreeMap)
  i = 3;
  while(i <= numNodes) {
    sourceNode <- i;
    destNode <- sample(i-1, 1);
    add.edge(g,sourceNode,destNode);
    increaseDegree(sourceNode, degreeMap)
    increaseDegree(destNode, degreeMap)
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return (list(graph = g, degreeMap = degreeMap))
}
```

As you see, I used a hash map to store the degree of each node and get it quickly whenever needed (see degreeMap variable and the functions increaseDegree and getDegree).

After that, you will have your first graph. However, you want a second graph where each node has the same degree as before. To do this, you can modify the randomGraph function and use the first graph to create the new one. So, the modified function will be something like:

```
newGraphPresevingDegree <- function(oldGraphObject) {
  oldGraph = oldGraphObject$graph
  oldDegreeMap = oldGraphObject$degreeMap

  numNodes = network.size(oldGraph)
  newGraph <- network.initialize(numNodes, directed = FALSE);
  newDegreeMap <- new.env(hash=T, parent=emptyenv())
  i = 1;
  while(i <= numNodes) {
    sourceNode <- i;
    sourceDesiredDegree = getDegree(sourceNode, oldDegreeMap);
    sourceCurrentDegree =  getDegree(sourceNode, newDegreeMap);
    while(sourceCurrentDegree < sourceDesiredDegree) {
      destNode <- sample(i:numNodes, 1);
      destDesiredDegree = getDegree(destNode, oldDegreeMap);
      destCurrentDegree =  getDegree(destNode, newDegreeMap);
      if(sourceNode != destNode && sourceCurrentDegree < sourceDesiredDegree
         && destCurrentDegree < destDesiredDegree && is.adjacent(newGraph,sourceNode,destNode) == FALSE) {
        add.edge(newGraph, sourceNode, destNode);
        increaseDegree(sourceNode, newDegreeMap)
        increaseDegree(destNode, newDegreeMap)
        sourceCurrentDegree =  getDegree(sourceNode, newDegreeMap);
      }
    }
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return (list(graph = newGraph, degreeMap = newDegreeMap))
}
```

Finally, you execute everything by doing:

```
# creating a random graph
numNodes = 3000;
oldGraphObject = randomGraph(numNodes)
oldGraph = oldGraphObject$graph
oldDegreeMap = oldGraphObject$degreeMap

#creating the new graph
newGraphObject = newGraphPresevingDegree(oldGraphObject)
newGraph = newGraphObject$graph
newDegreeMap = newGraphObject$degreeMap
```

And check if the degrees remains the same:

```
i = 1
while(i <= numNodes) {
  oldDegree = length(get.neighborhood(oldGraph, i))
  currentDegree = length(get.neighborhood(newGraph, i))
  if(oldDegree != currentDegree) {
    print(paste("old neighborhood of node", i))
    print(get.neighborhood(oldGraph, i))

    print(paste("new neighborhood of node", i))
    print(get.neighborhood(newGraph, i))
    print("------------")
  }
  i = i + 1
}
```